# JSTL - fmt:message and fmt:param toLowerCase

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have following JSTL:

```
<fmt:message key="localizationKey1">
   <fmt:param> 
      <fmt:message key="enumValue.${reputation}"/>
   </fmt:param>
</fmt:message>
```

enumValue.reputation gives strings like 'Very good', 'Perfect' and for this case I need to have it lowercase 'very good', 'perfect'. How to make it lowercased?

Comment: Would https://www.javatpoint.com/jstl-fn-tolowercase-function help?

Answer (score 0):

Store that translated message into a variable, and use `fn:toLowerCase` from [functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_tolowercase.htm) taglib.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"  %>  
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix = "fn" %>

<fmt:message key="enumValue.${reputation}" var="reputation"/>

<fmt:message key="localizationKey1">
   <fmt:param> 
       ${fn:toLowerCase(reputation)}
   </fmt:param>
</fmt:message>
```